# Clarification about read only and write only properties

Tags: apex

```
    public class AutomaticProperty 
  {
       public integer MyReadOnlyProp { get; }
       public string MyWriteOnlyProp { set; }
    }
```

could you please give any examples related to this concept.can we use any where only get and only set?

Thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V.Suresh,

You can take help from this link http://www.forcetree.com/2009/07/getter-and-setter-methods-what-are-they.html

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No problem mate, you can mark it as answer if it served your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

just because it exists, doesn't mean it is useful.

You could imagine something like a random number generator having a `Integer seed {set;}` property, but I'd be inclined to write `void setSeed(Integer x)` method instead.

Comment: Hi Mark,                                                                                                                            This post gave me a clear idea of get set.                                                                thankyou